# image resize using php image magician

Tags: php, html

i am trying to display an uploaded image along with text watermark in a different size using  php-image-magician without saving the image.

here are the codes :

```
<?php

$errors = array();

function mimeValidator($imagefile)
{
$imageInfo = getimagesize($imagefile);
$allowedMimes = array('image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png');

if(!in_array($imageInfo['mime'], $allowedMimes))
$errors[] = "Only jpg and png images are supported";
}

function renderImage($imageSource, $watermark, $fontSize, $font)
{
$imageInfo = getimagesize($imageSource);
list($width,$height) = getimagesize($imageSource);

if($imageInfo['mime'] == 'image/jpg' || $imageInfo['mime'] == 'image/jpeg')
$imageSource = imagecreatefromjpeg($imageSource);
elseif($imageInfo['mime'] == 'image/png')
$imageSource = imagecreatefrompng($imageSource);

$image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$blue = imagecolorallocate($image, 79, 166, 185);
$text = imagettftext($imageSource, $fontSize, 0, 20, ($height-20), $blue, $font,      $watermark);

ob_start();
imagejpeg($imageSource);
$image = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

return base64_encode($image);
}

?><html>
<head>
<title>
image Watermark and resize
</title>

<style type="text/css">
body{ width:800px; margin: 15px auto; padding:0px; font-family: arial}    

</style>
</head>
<body>
<form name="imageUpload" id="imageUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<fieldset>
<legend>Image text watermark</legend>
Text: <input type="text" name="text" id="text"/><br />
Image: <input type="file" name="image" id="image"/><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="createmark" value="Submit" />
</fieldset>   
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
if($_POST['text'] == '')
$errors[] = "Text is too short";

if($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] == '')
$errors[] = "Please upload a image";
else
mimeValidator($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

if(count($errors) == 0)
                {
include('php-image-magician/php_image_magician.php');

$magicianObj = new imageLib($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
$magicianObj -> resizeImage(100, 200);
$magicianObj -> saveImage($imagename);
echo "<img src=\"data:image/gif;base64," . renderImage($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],  $_POST['text'], 30, "./arial.ttf") . "\" />";
}
else
{
echo "<ul>";

foreach($errors as $error)
echo "<li>{$error}</li>";

echo "</ul>";
}

}
?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

i am getting an error "file C:\xampp\tmp\php9E3D.tmp is missing or invalid"
i am a newbee in this. please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I never used php-image-magician, so the following may very well be false information.

From what I see:

```
$magicianObj = new imageLib($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
```

Internally, `imageLib` calls `openImage` which in turn does the following:
1) it checks if the file actually exists
2) it checks the extension and uses the correct imagecreatefrom_*_*_ function.

This is where your problems start. When you upload files to your webserver, they get saved under a temporary filename (in your example, "php9E3D.tmp"). This extension (.tmp) is not in the list of allowed extensions for php-image-magician (.jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .png, .bmp, .psd). As such, the internal `image` variable gets set to false and the whole library won't work.

You have several options to tackle this issue:

1) Rewrite php-image-magician (specifically `openImage`), this however is not recommended.

2) Rename your uploaded file using `move_uploaded_file`, see Example #2 [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

3) Get rid of your dependency on php-image-magician and use PHPs internal functions (`imagescale` and friends, you're already creating an image resource to work with in your renderImage function)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good call! Could supply that there are many resize-scripts for PHP out there that are really well-written. Just do a simple Google-search.